# How can I get a substring from the middle of a file path in VBScript?

Tags: regex, vbscript, substring, indexof

I have the following string in VBScript:

```
myPath = "C:\Movies\12 Monkeys\12_MONKEYS.ISO"
```

The path C:\Movies\ is always going to be the same. So here is another path as an example:

```
myPath = "C:\Movies\The Avengers\DISC_1.ISO"
```

My question is, how can I pull only the movie folder name, so in the above examples I would get:

```
myMovie = "12 Monkeys"
myMovie = "The Avengers"
```

Is there a way to use RegEx with this? Or should I just do some substring and index calls? What is the easiest way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the code below:

```
arrPathParts = Split(myPath, "\");
myMovie = arrPathParts(2);
```

Split the string where the delimiter is the backslash character. Splitting a string returns an array of strings. Your movie is the third item in the array of strings.

Answer (score 0):

http://regexr.com?3332n

`(?<=C:\\Movies\\).*?(?=\\)`

You use assertions so that it finds a string that starts with `C:\Movies` but does not include it in the results, then a greedy operator to find everything up until the forward slash.  You use a look ahead assertion to exclude the forward slash from the results.

Comment: please consider to delete this answer as it does not apply to VBScript.