# Truncate String to first wildcard in VBS

Tags: string, powershell, vbscript, sql-server-2008-r2

I have the following expression, which goes to a SQL table (SQL Server 2008 R2) and grabs the file path to open (usually a PDF or photo) which is formatted to work as a hyperlink in our Access front-ends.

Here's what I'm doing in my VBS file...

```
Dim Input
Input = InputBox("Enter your WO#", "PDF Search", "ie. 40900500")

set conn2 = createobject("ADODB.Connection")
conn2.open "Driver={SQL Server}; Server=server; UID=user; PWD=password; Database=db;"    

dim sql2

msgbox("Testing fixture connection...")

dim rs2
set rs2 = createobject("ADODB.Recordset")

sql2 = "select Photo from Fixtures where Application = '" & input & "'"

rs2.open sql2, conn2

msgbox("It worked! Your photo is here: " & rs2.fields(0).value)
```

...which eventually returns this...

[image]

...and all I need is the file path prior to the first number sign (this message box was just to test the connection and show what data I'm working with).

How would I left truncate the field value I'm returning from SQL up to the first number sign so I can open the file via running a powershell object within my .vbs file?

Any assistance is always welcome! :)

Comment: If you look up splitting string in vbs you would find your answer. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13784445/how-can-i-get-a-substring-from-the-middle-of-a-file-path-in-vbscript. @Air s comments are also worth considering if there is no good reason for the string to look like that.

Comment: Why is your query returning the same path twice to begin with? I really doubt string manipulation is the answer to your underlying problem.

Comment: @Air It is possible the sample data shown would suggest redundancy bu perhaps not all values are like that. Op should be able to clarify.

Comment: What if you will loop the query output with `for each rsxx in rs2.fields : msgbox(rsxx.value) : next` ?

Comment: @Air, that's the whole value within the SQL table. It's double because this is being used as a hyperlink field within Access.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) You could use following expression to extract file path before first `#`:

```
sql2 = "select LEFT(Photo, NULLIF(CHARINDEX('#', Photo), 0) - 1) from Fixtures where  ..."
```

If some rows doesn't contain `#` then you could use:

```
sql2 = "select LEFT(Photo, ISNULL(NULLIF(CHARINDEX('#', Photo), 0) - 1, 260)) from Fixtures where  ..."
```

Test:

```
DECLARE @Photo VARCHAR(260) 
SET @Photo = 'J:\DRAWINGS\Folder1\File1.jpg#aaa#'

SELECT LEFT(@Photo, NULLIF(CHARINDEX('#', @Photo), 0) - 1) AS T1
-- J:\DRAWINGS\Folder1\File1.jpg

SET @Photo = 'J:\DRAWINGS\Folder1\File1.jpg'
SELECT LEFT(@Photo, ISNULL(NULLIF(CHARINDEX('#', @Photo), 0) - 1, 260)) AS T2
-- J:\DRAWINGS\Folder1\File1.jpg
```

2) You should avoid string concatenation in above line

```
sql2 = "select Photo from Fixtures where Application = '" & input & "'"
```

and you should use parameterized queries => see [SQL Injections](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953%28v=sql.105%29.aspx).

Comment: Thanks Bogdan! For both the answer as well as the hint on parameterized queries. The end users whom have access to this don't know anything about SQL, but this precaution might be necessary to take.